# How to find all roots of a complex number

Tags: numerics, complex, algebraic-manipulation, equation-solving

Finding all roots, and I know there are four f them, of this (1 - i)^(1/4)
Not only real, but imaginary as well

Comment: The duplicate here indeed is not really what your question is about. The answer by Mark should help you though (my motivation to close was that the solution can be found in the documentation).

Comment: It did help me a lot. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You mean like this?

```
Reduce[x^4 == 1 - I, x] // N
```

> ```
> x==-1.06955+0.212748 I||x==-0.212748-1.06955 I||x==0.212748+1.06955 I||x==1.06955-0.212748 I
> ```

Comment: Can also just use `Solve[x^4 == 1 - I, x]`

Comment: In this case, yes.  Though `Reduce` promises a complete set of results equivalent to the original expression, whereas `Solve` has caveats, such as: "Solve uses non-equivalent transformations to find solutions of transcendental equations and hence it may not find some solutions and may not establish exact conditions on the validity of the solutions found."